# jQuery, jQueryUI (and plugins) and AngularJS - how do they all fit together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs

I have this website (in Hebrew): http://www.iping.co.il (if you could have a look at it maybe with google translate and see what it does it could be great but not a must).

It basically a website that shows your IP, and gives you a set of tools (like ping, whois check, open port checks...).

I've built it a while back and I was using jQuery and jQuery UI to do all the work (like opening dialogs, call the server, change the DOM, show a progress bar...).

Now I'm working on rebuilding it - I'm rebuilding using ASP.NET MVC 5, HTML5 and Bootstrap3. I figured it's a great little website to test new things I've been reading about lately. And one of those things I would like to try and implement (after reading much about) is **AngularJS**.

As far as I know, AngularJS is not meant to change the DOM directly, but use directives and 2 way bindings to do so.

I have a lot of code, and plugins that I use that uses jQuery and jQuery UI to (for example the dialogs, the progress bar and so on... things that I haven't figured out how to do with AngularJS). It seems that if I use the jQueryUI progress bar and update it from from AngularJS that I'm breaking some rules here and that it's probably dirty and not the way it should be written.

So my question is, what is the correct way to work when and build a rich UI when using AngularJS? is jQuery and jQueryUI even still relevant? if so, is there a correct way to use them (maybe DI somehow?)?

I've searched and found something called AngularJS UI - but it's not as rich as jQueryUI.

Thank you

Comment: Without shameless dropping my own links here, I wrote a pretty popular post on learning Angular in a day, I'd take a good look at it and consider whether the framework is right for you: http://toddmotto.com/ultimate-guide-to-learning-angular-js-in-one-day. When it comes to jQuery, you'll probably be using a plugin or two, you can convert these to Directives, and use inside Angular seamlessly. As far as your "Angular not meant to change the DOM directly" - this is very incorrect as that's what the framework was built for HTML compiling.

Comment: @ToddMotto - Hey, I attached my link since I think it's relevant to see what the site functionality should look like (since I'm guessing the good people of StackOverflow are not my target audience since it's in Hebrew). How would I convert jQuery plugins to directives? as far as changing the DOM - for my understanding Angular is not meant to manipulate the DOM directly as part of it's MV* principle - for sake of seperation of concerns. Is that not true?

Comment: You're not meant to manipulate the DOM inside Controllers, you're meant to use Directives. As for how Controllers work, you feed the `$scope` the data, which populates the DOM. Should you remove/change this data, angular will update the DOM automatically. There should be no `$('.myElement')` style selectors/functions ever - only inside Directives should you need to.

Comment: @ToddMotto - that's what I meant (sorry if I wasn't more clear) - but we're on the same page. So if we take the progress bar for example - how would I implement one in Andgular but still using the jquery one and not HTML5 ? thanks

Comment: First I would decide what 'jQuery plugins' you'll be needing/using. If they don't need a Model/Controller binding, then I wouldn't bother 'converting' them to Angular. There are a few tutorials on the conversion, but I won't link drop more ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using plugins within directives is fairly simple in concept.

```
<div my-directive></div>
```

Following is a very minimialistic directive with just enough code to initialize a plugin. The returned function is equivalent to `link` in a more defined directive

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective',function(/* dependencies*/){
      /* element is a jQuery object when jQuery is included in page before angular.js*/
     return function(scope,element,attrs){
         /* can use attributes or scope to pass options to plugin if needed*/
          element.someJqueryPlugin();
     }
});
```

This would be equivalent to writing in jQuery only:

```
$(function(){
    $('[my-directive]').someJqueryPlugin();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use AngularJS and Bootstrap I suggest you take a look at these directives:

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Once you load the modules, you can set up say a progress bar this way:

```
    <progressbar max="max" value="dynamic">
            <span style="color:black; white-space:nowrap;">{{dynamic}} / {{max}}</span>
    </progressbar>
```

You shouldn't even need to include JQuery if you only need the Bootstrap components.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. What about other jQuery plugins that I download from the internet? and what about support for older browsers that don't yet support the progress bar tag? thanks.

Comment: Support for older browsers is documented here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie. Basically browsers under IE8 are not tested. For plugins that do not have a angular directive yet you can either write one for them or choose to include jquery in your project. Here's what I found in the Angular FAQ:

**Does Angular use the jQuery library?**
_Yes, Angular can use jQuery if it's present in your app when the application is being bootstrapped. If jQuery is not present in your script path, Angular falls back to its own implementation of the subset of jQuery that we call jQLite._